# (Dis-)Advantages of using generic git user for SSH based access

Tags: ssh, git

We are using the generic `git` user to access git repositories on our server via SSH. My understanding was, that this is kind of a defacto standard when accessing git repositories.

Now that we are migrating to another hosting provider, I have been asked why we would not use the normal user that we use to access the systems also for the git access.

To be honest, right now I can't come accross an idea, why we should not do that.

Are there any pros or cons why we should prefer the git user over another user or doesn't it make a difference? For example that we separate git access from other system access and can easily restrict access for this only user?

Comment: How do you revoke access for a single person? How do you audit who is actually logging in?

Comment: @gronostaj We can revoke/ remove single SSH keys for each user that connects via the git user. We are not currently actively auditing who connects to the git repos.

Answer (score 4):

If you only create an account named "git" and do *nothing else* with it then it's not much of advantage. Indeed it would often be better to use individual accounts (allowing you to control repository access via file permissions). The same restrictions that you apply to "git" can be applied to other accounts as well.

But typically, the "git@" user isn't just used by itself but together with a "smart" backend such as Gitolite (or Gitea/Gogs/GitLab), which applies different access levels depending on which SSH key was used (via `command=".."` tricks in the authorized_keys file). For example, while basic file permissions can restrict push access at repository level, the "smart" backend can do the same at branch level.

Generally these backends are *designed* to be run under the same UID for everyone (only distinguishing clients by their SSH key). They rely on the SSH server forcing you into the restricted environment, so that it is no longer possible for someone to directly access the repository files via SFTP or interactive SSH (preventing them from bypassing whatever access policy was defined, e.g. overriding receive-hooks) – but this means the account becomes unusable for actual server administration. Separating all Git access to the "git" account avoids that problem.

> How do you revoke access for a single person? How do you audit who is actually logging in? – gronostaj

You remove their SSH key from the authorized_keys file. Current OpenSSH sshd versions log the client's key fingerprint by default; in older versions it was mostly a matter of increasing log verbosity.

Comment: That's a helpful explanation. Wasn't aware that this might mainly make sense for the 'smart backends'.